# Excel - How to create numeric tag for cyclic data

Tags: excel

I'm running an experiment in cycles continuously. There's a parameter that idle between 0 and 100 for some time interval and a full cycle is when that parameter drops back to 0 (wave pattern), before continuing to another cycle.

Now, with the long list of raw data, how do you make a count-up counter or tag for each cycles? Eg:

```
    Parameter A     Cycle 
    -----------     -----
    0               0
    0               0
    100             1
    100             1
    0               0
    100             2
    100             2
    100             2
```

I'm trying to do this in order to extract data for intended nth cycle automatically using the following formula:

```
    =sumproduct((cell=Parameter A)*(cell=Cycle Number)*(range))
```

I'm trying to solve this without using VBA. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should cycle always be 0 when parameter A is 0? I used two adjacent cells to calculate the cycles, so the formula starts in B2.

`B2=IF(A2=0,0,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:A1<$A$2:A2)))`

Comment: It doesn't has to be 0. But thanks a lot. It works just fine

Comment: I can't figure out the logic when parameter A is 0. I need more examples for improving the formula if you need.

Comment: one of the parameter from my experiment, in this case, A, takes the form of sinusoidal signal, so basically i want to group all the data in a "n" wave as one cycle. The 0 and 100 is just the cut-off point from which i would like to extract the data from a single "n" wave. It can be any value but to make the situation simple, I chose 0 and 100